# Transpose row to column SQL server 2015

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

Need help to transpose the data from rows to columns

```
col1  col2   col3
-------------------
d1    d2      d3
```

Result should be

```
col
----
d1
d2
d3
```

Comment: look at pivot/unpivot

Comment: There is no SQL Server 2015, do u mean 2014 or 2016 ?

Comment: If my answer meets your expected result pls make it as accepted

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using Cross Apply

```
;WITH CTE(col1,col2,col3)
AS
(
SELECT 'd1','d2','d3'
)
SELECT col FROM CTE
CROSS APPLY (VALUES(col1),(col2),(col3)) As Dt (col);
```

Result,Look Demo: http://rextester.com/LVXO57980

```
col
---
d1
d2
d3
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use this:

```
SELECT col1 AS col
FROM table_name
UNION ALL 
SELECT col2 AS col
FROM table_name
UNION ALL 
SELECT col3 AS col
FROM table_name
ORDER BY col;
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this

```
Select col 
from tablename 
     unpivot ( 
        col
        FOR unpivot_columns IN ([col1],[col2],[col3])
     ) as unpvt;
```

Use this [link](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/3000/use-sql-servers-unpivot-operator-to-help-normalize-output/) for UNPIVOT Example