# Transpose varying dates from rows to columns in sql

Tags: sql, transpose

I have a query, example:

```
Letter |   Date
  A    | 2/22/12
  A    | 5/13/11
  A    | 6/11/20
  A    | 3/15/13
  B    | 9/30/15
  B    | 7/22/04
  C    | 2/24/16
  C    | 6/09/16
  C    | 5/01/11
```

So the dates themselves vary, and also the number of dates per letter vary.
I'd like to construct the following in sql:

```
Letter |   Date     |   Date1    |   Date2    |   Date3      
  A    | 2/22/12    | 5/13/11    |  6/11/20   |  3/15/13
  B    | 9/30/15    | 7/22/04    |    Null    |   Null
  C    | 2/24/16    | 6/09/16    |  5/01/11   |   Null
```

I saw a [similar post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50344970/transpose-row-to-column-sql-server-2015), but in my actual code the A,B,C identifiers are randomized 6 digit values, and there are thousands of them..

Any advise would be appreciated.

Comment: What is the order across the page of the dates?  Ascending, descending, random, some other field criteria?

Answer (score 0):

One method uses `row_number()` and conditional aggregation to pivot over a *fixed* number of columns:

```
select
    letter,
    max(case when rn = 1 then date end) date1,
    max(case when rn = 2 then date end) date2,
    max(case when rn = 3 then date end) date3,
    max(case when rn = 4 then date end) date4
from (
    select t.*, row_number() over(partition by letter order by date) rn
    from mytable t
) t
group by letter
```